# Add the end of page in XSSFSheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to export my data into .xlsx file. This works fine, but I need to control the content of document for proper print. Let's say that I have logical groups of my data ... I need to print this groups on the same page and when some group size doesn't fit to the rest of page, then **add end of page** mark to prevent split this group on two pages and ensure that this group will start on new page. 
Unfortunately I can't find how to add end of the page in javadoc of apache poi or on the internet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Workbook` class has a `String getPrintArea(int)`, a `void removePrintArea(int)` and a `void setPrintArea(int, String)`. The `int` is always the sheet index (which you either already have or can obtain via the workbook's `int getSheetIndex(Sheet)` method). The `String` is the print area definition as it appears in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that may work if the String with print area definition can contain more defined areas. In the meantime I bypass my issue by putting empty rows until end of current page which move other content to next page and solved my print problem.